# Find Majority: what if "not less than", instead of "more than" n/2?

Tags: c++, sorting, selection

We already have the code for find Majority:

```
for (int c = 0, i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    if (0 == c) {
        maj = A[i];
        c = 1;
    }
    else
        maj == A[i] ? c++ : c--;
return maj;
}
```

The array is unsorted:
e.g. array=[3,2,1,2,2], **'2'** is the majority , while in array=[3,2,1,2,2,0], there is no majority.
Now I want to make some extension: I change '＞' to '≥'. So in array=[3,2,1,2,2,0], '2' is what I want to find.

Can I use this algorithm to find element repeated **not less than**  n/2 times (instead of "more than") in an array with a little adjustment?

Comment: All numbers except the one repeated more than n/2 times (if any) are repeated less than n/2 times, so once you have found the "majority" number you have also found all the "minority" numbers.

Comment: Please explain what Majority means ! What is it supposed to find, exactly ?

Comment: Majority is an element that appears more than n/2 times in an array. But I wonder if some extension can be made. If the ‘＞’ changes to '≥', the algorithm above doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is the array sorted? Please show a [mre]

Comment: *"So in array=[3,2,1,2,2,0], '2' is what I want to find."* ??? That is what your current code returns for this input data. (Is it a problem that your code has no way to indicate whether or not there is a majority value?)

Comment: The correctness of this code is provable. In fact, if you set [0,2,1,2,3,2] as input, the output would be '3'. This code can truely find a majority when '>n/2', but fails when '≥n/2'.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot easily adapt it.

With the "more than" constraint there can only be 0 or 1 elements satisfying that.

With the "not less than" constraint, there can be 0, 1, or 2 elements satisfying that. For example, if `A` is {0, 1}.

Comment: Thanks！ So does it mean this question can't be done in a decrease and conquer way?